# Joomla: Editing/Adding Categories in the Front-end

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, frontend, joomla-extensions

How can I allow editing and adding categories from the front-end?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.joomla.org/User_Group_Access_levels_explained_in_simple_terms

well just allow these things for the right user group in the backend

Comment: An interesting article, but I don't understand how it answered my question?

Comment: you select in the backend and edit the permissions, should be easy  http://joomlawebhosting.ca/joomla-15-tips/180-joomla-user-group-permissions-who-gets-to-do-what.html   the right user group should be "editor"

Comment: I am still lost, I asked how I can allow people to edit the categories from the front-end and not who can view them.

Comment: it seems its just working out of the box in joomla 1.6  search for category on http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/5-commentary/84-introducing-the-new-permissions-in-joomla-16.html  why not upgrade joomla?

Comment: I actually had an old version of PHP on my server installed with xampp. Now that I've managed to upgrade that, I'm going to try upgrade to Joomla 1.6.

Comment: xampp on a productive system?

Comment: No, its still in development. Way to hard to upgrade to Joomla 1.6 now that I've already created the whole website. Going to just do without, or see if I can do it myself somehow. Thanks for the help.